# Variational formulation for elliptique equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{lll}
-\Delta u+u_{x}+u=1 & ,\quad & x\in\left(  0,1\right)  \times\left(
0,1\right)  \\
u=0 & , & \Gamma_{1}=\left\{  0\right\}  \times\left[  0,1\right]  \text{ and
}\Gamma_{2}=\left\{  1\right\}  \times\left[  0,1\right]  \\
\left\langle \nabla u,n\right\rangle =1 & , & \left[  0,1\right]
\times\left\{  0\right\}  \\
\left\langle \nabla u,n\right\rangle +u=3 & , & \left[  0,1\right]
\times\left\{  1\right\}
\end{array}
\right.  .
$$
I used the notation $<,>$ for scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n$ is the unit normal vector. We need to prove that this problem admits a unique solution. I don't know who
is the space of solution and how to define the bilinear form, linear form.
There is a book we some examples like this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can start wrinting the variational formulation of the elliptic second order problem. Moving $u_{x}$ in $RHS$, multiplying by
$$
v\in H_{\Gamma_{1},\Gamma_{2}}^{1}=\left\{  v\in H^{1}\mid v=0\text{ on
}\Gamma_{1}\cup\Gamma_{2}\right\}
$$
and then integrating we obtein (after applying a Green formula type) the
following variational formulation
$$
\text{Find }u\in H_{\Gamma_{1},\Gamma_{2}}^{1}\text{ such that }\forall v\in
H^{1}:\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+uv\operatorname*{dx}=\int_{\Omega
}v-vu_{x}\operatorname*{dx}+\int_{\partial\Omega}v\left\langle \nabla
u,n\right\rangle d\sigma,
$$
where $\cdot$ is the scalar product and $u_{x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.